# How to faithfully OCR a screengrab using tesseract command on Windows?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am trying to OCR a screengrab. Screenshot is shown below.

I have shown the relevant section that needs to be OCRed (using 3 arrows (yellow color))

I intend to OCR above sections so that I get following texts (post successful OCR):

`IFTY [N59901]19189.05 HI 18326.7 LO 18211.9`

[Screengrab is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKfcV.png)

I have utilized following commands (Windows OS) so far:

tesseract --psm 11 screengrab.png outfile.txt -l eng

tesseract --psm 6 screengrab.png outfile.txt -l eng

tesseract --psm 6 --oem 3 screengrab.png outfile.txt -l eng

tesseract -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789.FTYHILO screengrab.png outfile.txt -l eng

However, I get the following output in outfile.txt:
{

IFTY [N59901]19189.

Price Avg(E,200)

14%

Hi 18326.

#9000 Lo 18211.

Hegog Cl 18315.1]

}

It is reading 19189. but not 19189.05 ie. it seems to be missing number after decimal point.

What should I do so as to perform more faithful OCR?

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you forget to read the [docs](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/) and [search SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btesseract%5D%20improve%20result):

```
$ tesseract I_read_docs-ROI.png -

IIFTY [N59901]19189.05, 1.14%
rice Avg(E,200)
```

(first letters are skipped/not recognized because there are not on screenshot you provided.)